# Can you define $f(x)$ such that $2^{x}<f(f(f(x)))<2^{2^x}$?

Tags: functions, exponentiation, problem-solving

Can you define a real-valued function $f$ using standard arthimetical operations such that $2^{x} < f(f(f(x))) < 2^{2^x}$ for sufficiently large $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

I know that the rule $f(f(x))=2^{x}$ can't be established with standard arthimetical operations, but is it possible to find a function using standard arthimetical operations such that $2^{x}<f(f(f(x)))<2^{2^x}$ for sufficiently large $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If I recall correctly, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ every strictly increasing continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a [**functional $n$th root**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) $f$ (that is, $f\circ ...\circ f$ ($n$ times) is just $h$). So just set $n=3$ and look at say $h(x)=42^x$ (which is between $2^x$ and $2^{2^x}$). Again if memory serves, this $f$ can even be taken to be continuous.

Comment: I'd like an actually defined function using  standard arthimetical operations. Or if tht won't work even using integration.

Answer (score 1):

Following [half exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function) function does the trick. It only uses logarithms, exponentials and a linear function. (And an indicator function if you like.) For convenience I write $\exp_2(x) := 2^x = \exp(x\ln(2))$.

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x + 1/2  & \text{if } x \in [0, 1/2] \\
\exp_2(x- 1/2) & \text{if } x \in (1/2, 1] \\
\exp_2(f(\log_2(x))) & \text{if } x \in (1, \infty) \\
\log_2(f(\exp_2(x))) & \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 0)
\end{cases}
$$

By construction we have $f(f(x)) = \exp_2(x) = 2^x$. Furthermore it is easy to see that $\exp_2(x) > f(x) > x$. Therefore we get

$$2^{2^x} = \exp_2(\exp_2(x)) = f(f(f(f(x)))) > f(f(f(x))) > f(f(x)) = \exp_2(x) = 2^x.$$

The function $f$ is continuous but only piecewise differentiable.